# OpenGL: how to still keep objects in the centre of the screen, when entering full screen mode

Tags: opengl

Before entering into the fullscreen mode, the object is in the center of the sreen. But after entering the fullscreen, the object stays at the left bottom of the screen. Can anyone kindly help me solve this?

Answer (score 4):

Ensure that your viewport (`glViewport`) and projection is set up correctly.